# AngularJS : Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Very new to AngularJS... I have an input field where I want the first letter to be capitalized. I added the below directive:

```
.directive('capitalizeFirst', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $modelCtrl) {

            var capitalize = function (inputValue) {

                var capitalized = angular.uppercase(inputValue.substring(0, 1)) + inputValue.substring(1);
                if (capitalized !== inputValue) {
                    $modelCtrl.$setViewValue(capitalized);
                    $modelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return capitalized;
            };
            $modelCtrl.$parsers.push(capitalize);
            capitalize($scope[$attrs.ngModel]); // capitalize initial value
        }
    };
})
```

It works! But it fires an error in my console:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined**

Can anybody let me know what is wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems that you didn't check if inputValue is null.

```
.directive('capitalizeFirst', function () {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $modelCtrl) {

        var capitalize = function (inputValue) {
            if (!! inputValue) {
                 var capitalized = angular.uppercase(inputValue.substring(0, 1)) + inputValue.substring(1);
                 if (capitalized !== inputValue) {
                    $modelCtrl.$setViewValue(capitalized);
                    $modelCtrl.$render();
                 }
                 return capitalized;
            }
            return inputValue;
        };
        $modelCtrl.$parsers.push(capitalize);
        capitalize($scope[$attrs.ngModel]); // capitalize initial value
    }
};})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution for calling `str.slice(<start>,<end>)` when you are making an API call, and the page may load before the API call completes, so you will get an error saying:

**cannot read property 'substring' of undefined**

Here is my `angular/js/filters.js` simple code to evaluate that the `str` where we are calling `slice()` or `substring()` on exists first before slicing it:

```
angular.module('conciergeFilters', []).filter('ph', function() {
  return function(str) {
    if (!! str) {
        return "(" + str.slice(2,5) + ")" + str.slice(5,8) + "-" + str.slice(8,12);
        }
    return str;
  };
});
```

Also, here is a good blog post on the difference between `slice()`, `substring()` and `substr()` if trying to pick the right method to use:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2159-using-slice-substring-and-substr-in-javascript.htm